# bosh deploy error Error 190014

Tags: vsphere, bosh-deployer, cf-bosh

my bosh version is 1.3232.0
my platform is vsphere, i search the google and bosh site, it may relate to the cloud-config opt-in. but i have no idea anymore.

I create own mongodb release, when Upload the manifest, it throws Error 190014

```
Director task 163
  Started preparing deployment > Preparing deployment. Failed: Deployment manifest should not contain cloud config properties: ["compilation", "networks", "resource_pools"] (00:00:00)

Error 190014: Deployment manifest should not contain cloud config properties: ["compilation", "networks", "resource_pools"]
```

my manifest is :

```
---
name: mongodb3
director_uuid: d3df0341-4aeb-4706-940b-6f4681090af8

releases:
- name: mongodb
  version: latest

compilation:
  workers: 1
  reuse_compilation_vms: false
  network: default
  cloud_properties:
    cpu: 4
    datacenters:
    - clusters:
      - cf_z2:
          resource_pool: mongodb
      name: cf_z2
    disk: 20480
    ram: 4096

update:
  canaries: 1
  canary_watch_time: 15000-30000
  update_watch_time: 15000-30000
  max_in_flight: 1

networks:
- name: default
  type: manual
  subnets:
  - cloud_properties:
      name: VM Network
    range: 10.62.90.133/25
    gateway: 10.62.90.129
    static:
    - 10.62.90.140
    reserved:
    - 10.62.90.130 - 10.62.90.139
    - 10.62.90.151 - 10.62.90.254
    dns:
    - 10.254.174.10
    - 10.104.128.235

resource_pools:
- cloud_properties:
    cpu: 2
    datacenters:
    - clusters:
      - cf_z2:
          resource_pool: mongodb
      name: cf
    disk: 10480
    ram: 4096
  name: mongodb3
  network: default
  stemcell:
    name: bosh-vsphere-esxi-ubuntu-trusty-go_agent
    version: latest
jobs:
- name: mongodb3
  instances: 1
  templates:
  - {name: mongodb3, release: mongodb3}
  persistent_disk: 10_240
  resource_pools: mongodb3
  networks:
  - name: default
```

Answer (score 0):

solved, these parts should be put in an single file, and deploy to bosh